# Boost graph : Are add_edge and remove_edge thread safe?

Tags: c++, boost, graph, boost-graph

Are add_edge(src, dst, g) and remove_edge thread safe ?  Can these operations be done concurrently with multi-threading parallelism ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unless stated otherwise, no data structures/algorithms in the boost library are thread aware.

Also, these are generic free functions operating on the underlying graph type. So the thread-safety would depend on the underlying type.

In general, this makes `add_edge` and `remove_edge` thread neutral *at best*